# Name or notation for a function f(n) that equals 1 if n = 1 and 0 if n > 1

Tags: functions, notation

While solving number theory problems I sometimes I have to use a function that can be defined as

$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } n = 1, \\
0 & \text{ if } n > 1.
\end{cases}
$$

where $ n $ is a positive integer.

For example, using this function, we can define Euler's totient function as

$$ \varphi(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(\gcd(k, n))$$

where $ n $ is a positive integer.

Is there a name or notation for such a function already? I just want to make sure that I do not create my own notation for something that already has a popular name or notation in mathematics.

Comment: You can call it $\delta_1$, or $e_1$ for example.

Comment: The [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) or the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket#Counting) may be what you are looking for. In fact Wikipedia uses the Euler phi function as an example in the article for the Iverson bracket.

Comment: There's no standard name in the sense that that's the name mostly used. It's frequently denoted by $I$, $e$, $\delta$ or (rarer) $\Delta$, and sometimes it's written $\bigl\lfloor \frac{1}{n}\bigr\rfloor$.

Comment: I have seen $0^n$ used as an indicator function for $n=0$, so perhaps $0^{n-1}$ for an indicator function for $n=1$ if $n$ cannot be zero.

Comment: Since it is arithmetic you can use $\binom{1}{n}$ maybe.

Comment: You can call it indicator function or characteristic function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: @TheSilverDoe What does $e_1$ stand for? Is it a notation popularly used in literature?

Comment: @LoneLearner The vector space of all sequences that have a finite number of non-zero terms has a canonical basis $(e_1, e_2, ..., e_n, ...)$ where $e_n$ is the sequence which is $0$ everywhere, except at the rank $n$ where it is $1$. Here, $e_1$ is exactly the sequence of your question. I guess it is natural to see it as a vector of a canonical basis, and for that, the notation $e_1$ can be used.

Comment: You could also call it the indicator function for the set $\{1\}$, denoted $1_{\{1\}}$ or $\chi_{\{1\}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory, he calls this function $I$.

[image]

Part of Apostol's rationale is that $I$ acts like the identity element in the group of arithmetic functions (where Dirichlet multiplication is the operator), and so something like $I$ is a good name.

Elsewhere I've seen it called many things. There is no standard name, though there are lots of unambiguous names. If I were king of the notational universe, I might use Kronecker-delta based names like $\delta(\cdot)$, $\delta_1(\cdot)$, or $\delta_{[n=1]}(\cdot)$ --- but (fortunately) I am not king of the notational universe.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually called an indicator function in signal processing. It is denoted as either $\delta(1)$ or $\mathbb{1}_{n=1}$.

Comment: If $ \delta(1) $ is the function notation, how is the function usage written? $ \delta(1)(1) = 1 $, $ \delta(1)(2) = 0 $ and so on?

Comment: Yes. I think it should be written with a subscript, i.e., $\delta_k(n)$ which means $\delta_k(n)=1$ if $n=k$ and $\delta_k(n)=0$ otherwise.